# Where to look up error of sentry itself?

Tags: django, sentry, raven

We've set up sentry on our server and sometimes we've got errors while working with sentry web interface. It looks like this:

```
There was an internal server error while processing your request.

You may reference this error as 0f77c43f3ced487085e225207f11beef.
```

Since the error code is always changing I assume it's pointing to some kind of error ID in some storage. But I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an internal Sentry project. Usually it is located in the /sentry/ organization, but is not necessarily exposed to you in the UI as part of the organization selection.

There is an open ticket within Sentry to improve the visibility of this project:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/1514